# python problem with pandas dataframe of list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe in which every row is a list.

I want to search a value, but I've got an error. and I know my value exists.

I check this:

```
df["text list"][1] == ['رهبری']
```

and got:

```
True
```

then i need this:

```
df[df["text list"] == ['رهبری']]
```

and got this error:

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-42-f14f1b2306ec> in <module>
    ----> 1 df[df["text list"] == ['رهبری']]

    ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py in wrapper(self, other, axis)
       1205             # as it will broadcast
       1206             if other.ndim != 0 and len(self) != len(other):
    -> 1207                 raise ValueError("Lengths must match to compare")
       1208 
       1209             res_values = na_op(self.values, np.asarray(other))

    ValueError: Lengths must match to compare
```

Comment: Not sure, but maybe: `df[df["text list"] == [['رهبری']]]`

Comment: no, I got the same error

Comment: write down your dataframe...

Comment: `df[df['text list'].apply(lamda x: x == ['رهبری'])]`? It's all speculating since you should provide a small example dataset where we can reproduce your error with.

Comment: I reproduced the error with this minimal frame:

```
test_frame =pd.DataFrame(data = {'test list': [['entry1'], ['e1', 'e2']],
                                 'column2': [1, 2]})
test_frame['test list'][0] == ['entry1']
>>> True
test_frame[test_frame['test list'] == ['entry1']]
>>> error
```

Comment: @Erfan your solution works with my minimal example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass the list directly to your DataFrame for comparison, it expects an array with the same size to make an element wise comparison.

To avoid this, we can use `apply` to check on each row if the list is present:

```
# example dataframe
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'text list':[['aaa'], ['bbb'], ['ccc']]})
>>> df
  text list
0     [aaa]
1     [bbb]
2     [ccc]
```

Use [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) to check for `[bbb]`:

```
>>> m = df['text list'].apply(lambda x: x == ['bbb'])
>>> df[m]
  text list
1     [bbb]
```

---

Since we are using `apply` which is basically a "loopy" implementation in the background.  We can avoid using the overhead of pandas and use list comprehension:

```
>>> m = [x == ['bbb'] for x in df['text list']]
>>> df[m]
  text list
1     [bbb]
```